# While running python from nodeJS, program shows python module import error

Tags: javascript, python, node.js

This is part of my python code which works when executing by itself.

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials, firestore
import nltk
import docx2txt
from pdfminer.high_level import extract_text
from analysis import get_tech_result, get_management_result, get_softskill_result, feedback

nltk.download('stopwords')
nltk.download('punkt')

cred = credentials.Certificate("service_key.json")
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)
```

However, when I try to run this code via node, with this code.

```
const { spawn } = require('child_process');

const childPython = spawn('python', ['resume_analysis/main.py']);

childPython.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log(`stdout: ${data}`);
});

childPython.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
    console.error(`stderr: ${data}`);
});

childPython.on('close', (code) => {
    console.log(`Child process exited with code: ${code}`);
});
```

It shows the following error:

```
stderr: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "resume_analysis/main.py", line 2, in <module>
    import firebase_admin
ImportError: No module named firebase_admin

Child process exited with code: 1
```

Since I am new to JavaScript, I don't have much knowledge on why it is showing me errors since the python code itself works fine.

Comment: Your Python program is in a separate directory. When you run the Python code directly, do you do it from the `resume_analysis` directory? Python has to be able to find the modules; if your Node process is running in a different working directory, you have to take that into account.

Comment: I tried running the program putting all the files (node_modules, .py files, .js files, and everything else) in the same folder, and executing it, but it is still showing the same error.